# How can I determine that I'm executing inside an Obj-C method?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to use an assert macro that wraps both `NSAssert` for ObjC methods, and plain `assert` (or something else) inside of C functions.

Is there a clean way to detect at runtime (or better yet, compile time!) that I'm currently executing inside an ObjC method?

I know that `self` and `_cmd` will be defined and valid within a method, but I'm not sure if there's an obvious way to safely check for the existence of a local variable. Am I forgetting something obvious?

Comment: How would that work at compile time? Maybe im misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @JustinMeiners: No idea, perhaps the llvm/clang preprocessor magically produces some constant that's defined inside methods but not elsewhere?

Comment: It looks like you have a mixture of Obj-C and C files, am I right? Would it not be correct to assume that `NSAssert` is used inside Obj-C method, when `assert` in a C function?

Comment: @BenZotto ah I see what your asking - if you can determine if a particular section of code is in objc or C method. I don't know of anyway you could determine that. NSAssert takes a different set of arguments? What would be the benefit of the abstraction?

Comment: @JustinMeiners. NSAssert is itself a macro that references self/_cmd special variables; it won't compile in a C function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the standard predefined macro to test if the file is compiled by an objective-c compiler.

```
//in the header file
#define MyAssert(A) NSAssert(A) assert(A)

//in the C file
#if !defined(__OBJC__)
#define NSAssert(A) 

//in the Obj-C file
#if defined(__OBJC__)
#define assert(A) 


/**/
f()
{
//...
MyAssert(TestCase && "Error Message");
//...
}
```

Comment: This won't catch plain C functions mixed in with a .m file, but fair enough; this seems like the best available approach. Thanks.