# Can I detect the existence of a local variable inside a macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to safely check to see whether some named variable (let's call it "foo") is present in the current scope? I'd like to have a macro that, say, makes use of "foo" if it's present, otherwise does something else. Are there any runtime tricks I can make use of here?

(The actual context is trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557663/how-can-i-determine-that-im-executing-inside-an-obj-c-method), but I realized that one could be a special case of this one, so a separate question seemed also interesting.)

Comment: Can you make your logic independent of your construction ?

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh: Not sure what that means?

Comment: Some how you may can do whats you want with the help of compiler, likes what Linux kernel do with the help of GCC .Or write your own checker .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The compiler is responsible for parsing variable names and assigning scopes to them, and the preprocessor runs before the compiler. So it has no access to that information.

Comment: Fair point. But perhaps the macro is a red herring; are there any clever runtime tricks that the macro could set up? Or is any attempt to detect the existence of a variable doomed to compile-time errors?

Comment: @BenZotto I'm not aware of any. And I looked pretty hard over the years as it would make it possible to write more portable code. I'm using GNU Autoconf for that, but it would be so much nicer to be able to tell whether a specific variable or function is available directly in preprocessor code. But it just doesn't seem possible.